# Add COMPOSE to WindowManager - Android

Tags: android-activity, android-jetpack-compose, transparent, android-windowmanager

```
@Composable
fun Welcome(){
Text(text = "Hello world!")
}


val window = context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE) as WindowManager
```

How to add compose to window:

```
window.addView(Welcome(), mParams)
```

I want to build an app: has view abow other app, but still click with other app, and use compose android.
Thanks!